# Installing CouchDB 1.0.1

Tags: 10.04, server, couchdb

I have Ubuntu server 10.04 and it comes with its own couchdb version 0.10  I am trying to upgrade this to 1.0.1 or at least install 1.0.1 on the side.  No matter what I try, I can't seem to be able to do it.  Things I have tried are below:

- `sudo apt-get install couchdb` (installs something, but when I use curl to check on it, it gives me the Welcome JSON with a version number 0.10)
- `sudo apt-get upgrade couchdb` (installs a whole bunch of stuff, same result)
- `sudo apt-get remove couchdb` (somehow still running - also purged.  now, I can curl to http://127.0.0.1:5984 and get the welcome JSON, but couchdb is not installed any more i.e. typing in couchdb stop gives me a "not installed" error)
- Installed from the 1.0.1 binary, but after installation, it is not actually running - tested with netstat)
- Tried to change the port number in the local.ini file and tried to restart, but now can't figure out how to restart couchdb1.0.1 or even if it is actually running.

In case I haven't made it abundantly clear, I am completely new to linux.  I have some rudimentary experience with .htaccess and configuring Apache and PHP but that's it.  If you can help me, I will be very grateful!

Comment: I've finally got it to work, as an FYI to anyone else stuck after installing via the .bin: you need to go and modify permissions on the installation folders to use the couchdb user.  I changed the port number to avoid conflicting with the 0.10 version.

Comment: I think I should add - it's taken me most of the day to find this, but you also need to change permissions on the .delete folder in install_dir/var/lib/couchdb to allow the couchdb user to write to it.  Otherwise, you will not be able to delete.

Comment: You should rewrite these comments into a second answer below :)

Comment: I'm having similar problems. I'm running ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop, but I ran into the same errors and problems. I'm reading your comments, but it's still slightly unclear to me how to resolve this...

Comment: Sorry @Costa, I didn't read your comment until recently.  I won't be of much help as I abandoned this early last year.  I do remember having it working, but other than the comments above, I don't remember much.  For couchdb, I am currently favouring heroku and not using my own server at all. From what I can remember, it was to do with permissions on the folders where you install couchdb.  There is a couchdb user and this user needs to have permissions to the install directories, and special permissions to the .delete directory in the location above.

Comment: cont ... These were the only steps apart from changing the port number of the new couchdb.  You have to use a different port number because you are running both couchdbs side-by-side and leaving the internal one alone.

Comment: I ended up installing a full build of erlang spidermonkey and couchdb in a new folder, and running it from there.  Seems to be working error free right now.  I have an http://IrisCouch.com too, that's been really helpful, so glad it's free, Thanks Iriscouch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest you use our [stable ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuone/+archive/stable)? CouchDB from there will be landing in 10.04 backports soon.

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: Thank you, I did come across your posts from other threads.  It was next on my list, but I seem to have fixed my problems.  I have no doubt it is probably a much simpler solution to the one I followed.